# Can I have splices in an electrical panel?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Adding 220 to garage no room in my 125 amp main panel. Subpanel will be 10 ft from main will be removing 3 15amp and 1 20 amp  breaker to add 50 amp breaker in its place.
I'm I allowed to have splices inside of main panel or will I have to add J boxes for circuits that were transferred to subpanel

Comment: I am going to edit this question to change "spices" to "splices". I cannot imagine anyone wanting to keep oregano or garlic powder in their breaker panel. Besides that I think the "spices" has already been confused by Tester101 as "spaces".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can have splices in the panel to extend wire to reach breakers.

What you cannot do is have splices where a wire enters the panel, is then spliced to another wire that exits the panel.

Comment: it is good to know splices are allowed--I didn't realize that! But I don't understand the scenario you describe of a non-allowed splice--when would that be a temptation? What is the difference between entering and exiting the panel?